# Transform matrix calculation for image registration known the relative camera poses

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, projective-geometry, computer-vision

I'm working on a problem where I define some positions of a chaser around an target object and take pictures of the same target with 2 cameras separated by a baseline.
[Example of the described problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M13ao.png)

I then have the two source images and need to register them.
[Image captured by the first camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOtpi.jpg).
[Image captured by the second camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlEBA.jpg).

For the assumed problem I posses the intrinsic camera parameters and can retrieve the relative pose between the two cameras.
I know that image registration can be tackled in different ways but all require the identification of features to match or correspondance of coordinates in the two pictures.

My question is: is there a way to calculate the transformation matrix to be applied to the second image in order to align it to the first one just by knowing relative positions and orientations between the two cameras ?